# VueJS: Compiler error states data property doesn't exist when access via this property

Tags: vue.js

I'm getting an issue that only seems to be a problem with my compiler. It doesn't like that it can't find properties I've defined in the data section. If I replace 'this' with '(this as any)' it runs just fine. That leads me to believe that I have an issue with typescript that I need to fix. The error message is very specific to my situation but I'm not sure how to fix it.

[image]

EDIT to add shims-vue.d.ts

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue';
  export default Vue;
}
```

Comment: It looks like TypeScript does not know how it should handle Vue files. The `this` in your error refers to the `computed` object and not to the component.
How do you compile your code?

Comment: I use, "vue-cli-service serve" to build and host the code. I think it uses webpack... but I'm not sure honestly.

Comment: Do you have a `vue-shims.d.ts` in your project? Also your lines 67 to 69 look funky because you say `(this as any).`. Generally you don't need to say any at all because `this.` is perfectly fine. The use of `any` pretty much defeats a core purpose of using TS in the first place

Comment: (this as any) is my work around for the issue I'm asking about. It allows the code to be compiled and it works fine at runtime. If I replaced the this that the compliler is complaining about with (this as any) it would compile and work just fine. I just agree with you that it looks funky and I don't like doing it. I'd love to figure this issue out and remove them all. Edited my question to include the vue-shims.d.ts file I'm using. Not sure what it does though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up fixing this was my declarative statement.
My error:

```
export default {
    name: 'Home',
    components: {
        ...
    },
    ...
};
```

The fix:

```
export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'Home',
    components: {
        ...
    },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears computed properties may require explicit type annotations, [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51984573/2411713). Instead of

```
items() {
...
}
```

you'd have

```
items(): ItemType[] {
...
}
```

Typescript should then understand the `this` reference. It's also worth considering the [class component syntax](https://class-component.vuejs.org/), which in my experience is better suited for typescript in Vue 2 (this issue wouldn't happen).